# Bug in Android app when migrated question/answer author does not have profile on target site

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, android-app, migrated-questions

This question was migrated to **Law**: [Are the names of guns protected under copyright law in the US?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/are-the-names-of-guns-protected-under-copyright-law-in-the-us)

On the Android App, the name appears, and is, clickable, even though they don't have a profile on Law (this question came from GameDev).

[image: Screenshot of question in Android app showing asker name as clickable]

However, upon clicking on that, it leads to a connection error message.

[image: Screenshot showing image of connection error message that appears after pressing on user profile link in question]

This also happens with the first answer, whose author does not have a profile on Law either.

---

Environment info:

- App version: <strike>1.0.68</strike> This still occurs on **1.0.71**
- Android version: 5.1.1

Comment: Repro'd on v1.0.70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Users without accounts (and community) will show up in the same color as Asked and Answered and not take you anywhere.